# ParserError in Solidity 0.8.0

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

#### hello Guys !

i'm trying to create a Dapp contracts it works perfectly in 0.4.2 but giving me errors in

latest Sol compiler version.

```
    pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.0;
    function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) ));
        admin.transfer( address payable(this).balance)
    }
}
```

### ERROR

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Payable should be the recipient**, not the sender address. Also, your syntax is slightly incorrect.

Assuming `admin` is saved as `address` (not payable)

```
payable(admin).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

And if `admin` is already `address payable`, it's enough to call just this

```
admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
```